# Retrieve the max date among the preceding dates if the time difference in months is one

Tags: dax

I'm currently facing an issue with a code that aims to find the maximum date among the consecutive preceding dates. Specifically, I want to retrieve the max date if the time difference in months between the current row and the previous row is exactly one. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to achieve the expected result despite my efforts.

It is important to note that sometimes there are two charges within the same month, with the same charge type and same tenant that I would like to count as one for this purpose.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone from the community could assist me with this matter. Thank you in advance for your help!

This is my code:
`= MAXX( FILTER( ALL('rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'), 'rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[Tenant Code] = EARLIER('rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[Tenant Code]) && 'rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[Charge Type] = EARLIER('rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[Charge Type]) && rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges[Charge Type] = "HAPRent" ), IF (  'rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[PreviousDate] - EOMONTH(EARLIER('rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[PreviousDate]), 0) <= 1, 'rx_Tenant_Unpaid_Charges'[PreviousDate], BLANK() ) )`

This is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcAJH.png)

And this is the expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3JO.png)

Answer (score 0):

@mods: sorry, posting as guest without enough reputation points does not provide me option to “comment”, so I am “answering“ here ..

@kROIyex: this would be my approach

- Create a helper column “continuous”: For each row, I would create/filter a list of dates for each tenant, where the dates are **after** the date of the current row. If the MIN of these dates is equivalent to EOMONTH of date of the current row + 1 day, set to 1, otherwise set to 0
- Define measure “end of period”: filter again a list of dates for each tenant with dates **>=** the current date having a 0 in the helper column. Pick the MIN Date from that list

This works independently to the actual row order of your list (as it follows the sequence of the dates per tenant regardless the row position).

If you certain about the row order is always correct, you might find a simpler way with the windows functions of DAX referring to the row order of your source table.

Comment: @kROIyex: have you been able to solve it? My proposal works also regardless another charges with same month etc., which you want to count as one.